# The array is not expending but keeps holding only 1 changing element

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm reading line by line from a given file and I want to store in an array called `arrayOfAllLines` 
only lines which are unique lines - meaning, if there are 2 identical lines in the file, I want to store only 1 of them.

I defined the array: `arrayOfAllLines` which is supposed to hold only the unique lines. I read the lines using a pointer called `newLine` and I compare each iteration its value with all the
lines that I already stored till that same point in my array.

The problem is that instead of adding lines - I override the lines that I stored in the previous iteration. Meaning, if you execute my code, take a look at the line: `printf("%s\n", arrayOfAllLines[0])` - its value is changing every iteration and I want to set it permanently.

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{   
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    const char *arrayOfAllLines[1000];
    char newLine[128];
    int areLinesIdentical = 0;
    int indexOfCurrentLine = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(newLine, sizeof newLine, file) != NULL ) {
        for (i = 0; i < indexOfCurrentLine; i++) {  
            if (strcmp(newLine, arrayOfAllLines[i]) == 0) {
                areLinesIdentical = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (areLinesIdentical == 0) {
            arrayOfAllLines[indexOfCurrentLine] = newLine;
            indexOfCurrentLine++;
        }
        areLinesIdentical = 0;
        printf("%s\n", arrayOfAllLines[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reset areLinesIdentical in every while() iteration.

Problem 2 is you assign same pointer to your single input buffer into all array items.
Consider using _strdup() when assigning it to array.

Comment: Problem found. Use arr[i]=strdup(line)

Answer (score 0):

You always read new lines into the same buffer `newline` and store a pointer to that buffer.  With every `fgets()` you overwrite the buffer.  If you reset `LinesIdentical` with every new start of the loop as [Anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178823/anonymous) has suggested,  you will end up with an array with a number equal to the number of unique lines,  but each filled with pointers to the same buffer holding the last line of your input file.

To achieve what you are aiming at you need to allocate (`malloc`) a new buffer each time you have found a new unique line and not forget to release (`free`) the memory once you don't need the array anymore.